# Using IN and Startswith operators together

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, startswith, in-operator

I am trying to add a `startswith` operator to my formula below, because I need it to return all values starting `TRA` or `MTA`.

```
IF {STK_LOCATION.LOC_CODE} 
   IN ['TRA', 'MTA'] 
   THEN {STK_LOCATION.LOC_STOCK_CODE}
ELSE {STK_LOCATION.LOC_STOCK_CODE} + LEFT({STK_LOCATION.LOC_CODE},4)
```

Comment: Where is startswith in formula

Answer (score 0):

The *IN* function compares your input with the whole string. Try *startswith*:

```
IF({STK_LOCATION.LOC_CODE}  startswith["TRA","MTA"]) THEN
    {STK_LOCATION.LOC_STOCK_CODE}
ELSE
    {STK_LOCATION.LOC_STOCK_CODE} + LEFT({STK_LOCATION.LOC_CODE},4)
```

And use always double quotes when you use strings, CR is not SQL